# TCP connect fails with certain websites

Tags: tcp, wireshark, windows-10

I am running Windows 10.  I am unable to browse a few seemingly random websites (CBS.com is one of them) using any of my browsers, although I can successfully ping all of them. Also, other computers on the network do not have the same problem, and my computer does not have this problem on other Wi-Fi connections. The same connection time out error occurs when I use the IP address instead of the website name.

Using wireshark, if I go to a working website, I see a TCP [SYN] sent by me, a [SYN, ACK] sent back and a final TCP [ACK] before I send a HTTP GET request.

However, when I attempt to load the non working sites, using either the URL or IP address on different browsers, or Curl, the following happens:

1. After the initial TCP [SYN] packet, I receive at TCP [SYN, ACK]
   packet with a [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT] error.
2. I send a second TCP [SYN] with the same result.
3. Then I send a few [TCP Spurious Retransmission] packets, with each one being followed by a receipt of a [TCP Retransmission] with the same [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT] error.
4. The above all happens again, and then the request times out and connection attempts stop.

Does anyone have any advice for solving or troubleshooting?  I haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: I've never seen such error before. Is that a https connection?

Comment: No.  The IP address I am using is 64.30.228.49, which brings me to www.cbs.com/shows/60_minutes (on my other computers)

Comment: that particular error is wireshark speccific, and likely a false positive: https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/22483/ethernet-frame-check-sequence-incorrect . As for your issue, I'd probably concentrate on the problem at a higher scope. try cleaning your browser cache, or perhaps reinstalling it altogether, updating your NIC drivers, try a different NIC, confirm that windows is integral with sfc.exe.

Comment: Clearing the browser cache doesn't work, and it fails for multiple browsers so I dont expect it to be an issue there.  I tried your idea and reinstalled the wireless network adaptor, (Qualcom  QZA 9377) but that didn't work:/  I will update on the response to the sfc.  Thanks

Comment: The src run did not find any integrity violations.  Any other ideas?  what different NIC should I try?

Comment: If the Ethernet FCS really is wrong, it's probably your router's fault. Reboot your router. Especially if it's your NAT gateway.

Comment: It is a gateway, but I jest tried rebooting it again, but this does not help either.. Any other ideas?

Comment: I wonder if the windows `ipconfig` can show the interface's errors, like the `ifconfig` on Unix can?

Comment: @Adam Did you find this issue?